# Autoformat pom.xml without using m2eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, code-formatting, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I don't use the Eclipse maven plugin while developing in Eclipse.

I generate my Eclipse classpath externally using the following command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This has worked fine for quite some time and I am not inclined to add a maven plugin.

However, I would like to be able to "autoformat" my pom.xml file.

My pom.xml is not showing up as a "Source" file and therefore the contextual "Source" menu doesn't show up.

**Control-Shift-F** doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this without installing the m2eclipse plugin? Is there any other generic "XML Editor" plugin that can help with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may be missing something obvious but why don't you use Eclipse's built-in **XML Editor** which supports formatting (via the regular <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I mentioned that in the question. Will highlight it.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F appears to work only for "Source" files. Since the pom.xml is not a source file, it doesn't work for it.

Comment: @hashable It definitely works for me with **any** XML file when I open them with the **XML Editor** which is part of [Eclipse for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/java.php) (**right-click** on an XML file then **Open With > XML Editor**). If you don't have it, install it (I think it's part of Eclipse WTP).

Comment: Sorry. It works with XML Editor. My eclipse was opening it with the standard text editor for some weird reason. Thanks.

Comment: This level of complexity is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a way -

1. Select source of pom.xml (ctrl+A).
2. Click right button of mouse.
3. Then click Source > Cleanup Document.
4. Check "Format Source" in popup and uncheck all other options.

it's Done!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctrl + shift + F` keys together, for me left side of `ctrl + shift` key combination of laptop did't work I tried with right side combination and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs only when we open in text editor. Solution works when we open the pom.xml in xml editor and use the short cut commands as shft+ctl+F