# How to set formatting setting for Maven POM Editor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, formatting

When I open up pom.xml with `Maven POM Editor` and try to format using default shortcut `ctrl + shift + f` I expect the file to be formatted as any other .xml with rules that are configured in `Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor`. However it is not.

```
Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Eclipse Build id: 20220310-1457
```

I need to open pom.xml with `XML Editor` instead. `Maven POM Editor` formats pom.xml in its own way, that I did not find settings in preferences for.

This is where I find that I need to open it in `XML Editor`: [Autoformat pom.xml without using m2eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885727/autoformat-pom-xml-without-using-m2eclipse-plugin)

`Maven POM Editor` brings some features and advantages when editing pom.xml over `XML Editor` (dependency tree, effective pom, navigation in outline...), which I would like to preserve, but also want formatting to be done in my way (with the setting I choose).

Is there a way to set formatting setting for Maven POM Editor?

Comment: Does it not trigger the formatting or does it format according to wrong rules?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Formatting is triggered, but it formats to wrong rules (Not those in Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor).

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/240

Comment: @Howlger Any expected time/if the bug will be fixed?

Comment: @Wortig Provide a pull request for the missing formatting options or find someone who does. Mickael Istria, who is one of the developers of this project, merged my last pull request in less than two hours. ;)

Answer (score 0):

General -> Editors -> Text Editors

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35847141)

Comment: @Shiham: There is no link here.

Comment: @president-james-k-polk Answer links to a path in software, which is somewhat a link. A screenshot with some explanation could have helped than just sharing the path. That is what I meant.